# How can I enable TLS verification in Influxdb2.4 client

Tags: ssl, https, verification, influxdb-2

I have generated Self-signed certificates with openssl and started influxd with certificate.key and certificates.crt

When I want to connect influxdb server with influx2cli, I cant find the command line to make influx2cli connect influxdb with my certificate, the only related command I find is --skip-verify to skip TLS verify.

But I wonder if there is a command to inform influx2cli the path of my certificate.key

```
# echo "poconnect,to=4838,from=5412 orphan_directory=0,waiting_directory=0,no_remote_directory=1" |  influx write -c ctrlflux-dev --bucket BUCKET
Error: failed to write data: Post "https://ctrlflux-dev.pol.be:8086/api/v2/write?bucket=BUCKETS&org=MYORG&precision=ns": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[root@gvcantw-ffs ~][1]#
```

How to **AVOID** the message WITH **checking the certificate** and WITHOUT killing any idea of any possible future security ?

Comment: I know option `--skip-verify` does exists.  Is there any `--CA-file` option?

Answer (score 0):

With open source version, we might be stuck with that skip option. Or similarly, use the -k flag to skip certificate verification. See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.4/security/enable-tls/) and it seems that InfluxData didn't resolve this [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4090) yet.

However, you could let the server know that you are using slef-signed certificate and make it work in Enterprise version by setting this configuration in influxdb-meta.conf file:

```
  # If using a self-signed certificate:
  https-insecure-tls = false
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/enterprise_influxdb/v1.10/administration/configure/security/enable_tls/).

Comment: Thx, but enterprise version is not fit for my requirement, it looks like I can only use skip as a transition method now.

Comment: The question is to ENABLE the SSL layer security not to DISABLE it.  Are you in need to learn how to read?

Comment: And sorry your link does not say how to enable TLS certificate verification.

Comment: I just updated the config to "https-insecure-tls = false" so that you can have TLS enabled.